# how to hide some properties after receiving result when saving mongoose object?

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I know I can hide some properties from mongoose model using select when I performing find query like this:

```
Product.find()
    .select("-__v")
    .then((products) => {}
```

but when performing `save()` , `.select()` doesn't work, and give error

> "TypeError: (intermediate value).save(...).select is not a function"

```
const user = await new User({
        email: email,
        password: hashedPassword
      }).save().select("-password")
```

I want to remove the password from user object, after successfully saving the user object. how to do that using mongoose ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.save()` is not a query you can't chain query helpers.

delete the property after you insert the document

```
let user = await new User({
  email: email,
  password: hashedPassword
}).save()

user = user.toObject();

delete user.password;
```

Comment: unfortunately the password properties is still included  if using delete user.password;

Answer (score 2):

simply Update Your User Model with the following Property.

```
password: {
    type: String,
    select: false //prevent password to show in query results
},
```